# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

You guys have gotten your own design and graduated, hurrah! And with that, you now have the opportunity to setup Community Promotion Ads for your own site, not just to apply to other sites.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- academic websites and resources
- interesting campus story blogs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/907).

Answer (score 28):

[image: PHD Comics]

Comment: Academia.SE answers my concrete questions ("What's the solution to this problem"). PHD Comics answers my (equally pressing) but totally subjective questions ("Am I the worst PhD student ever? Should I just drop out of grad school now before I embarrass myself further?") with humor and companionship. I think this is a site worth sharing through community promotion.

Comment: I love PHD Comics, but shouldn't we focus more on things which: 1) are not already known by every PhD, 2) are more "for greater good", not only - fun? (Read: see other proposals and consider upvoting them. :))

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I think that a good sense of humour and availability of relax is important for a community to feel good :)

Answer (score 25):

[image: arXiv.org -- Open access to over 900,000 e-prints!]

Comment: Shamelessly stolen from [Physics SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/community-promotion-ads-2014#5266).

Comment: Thank you for that! Now I can upvote it here.

Comment: Great, though [this one from Physics.SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5299/184) is IMHO even better.

Comment: OK, I posted it [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1046/49).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Internet Archive]

Comment: And their wonderful [Wayback MAchine](https://archive.org/web/web.php) immortalizing volatile websites.

Comment: Hi @PiotrMigdal, I used a similar picture on [Phys.SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/5733/3). The response I got was [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/community-promotion-ads-2014/5733#comment16929_5733). So since this image is not descriptive '-1' :-(

Comment: @user31782 I thought that this name is self-explanatory (and the sign is nice). Do you genuinely share this view (i.e. that it is better to have nothing than the above logo) or just copy the behaviour you have experienced/

Comment: I am familiar with archive.org so it causes me no problem to understand that it is the logo of archive.org. What to say, It would be good to have a more descriptive ad so as anyone totally unfamiliar with it could get a more insight view at the first sight. Keeping in mind that this is going to be an advertisement it should be improved. What do you think about my try below. I copied the layout from [arXive](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/931/13359) :-p

Comment: @user31782 Let me reiterate: "Internet Archive" is self-explanatory. Adding "Library of Internet" or "It is archive of the Internet" is not necessary.

Comment: Could you somehow edit this post so that I can revert my downvote to an upvote. For some time I've been downloading and reading books from archive.org. I find it very useful. When I got downvotes on my post I was very much disappointed. Thank you very much for this post. Could you do another favor to me? Could you also post about archive.org on [Physics meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5263/31782). My similar post there is downvoted :-(.

Comment: @user31782 I upvoted you there (some time ago, when you send link). I also edited it. And added ][one more link](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1045/49) (exactly to the Wayback Machine).

Comment: Hi @PiotrMigdal, would you mind us featuring this as a [community promotion ad](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/19675/community-ads-proposal-and-voting?show=19756#a19756) on PO too? I am asking because of copy right issues (?) ...

Comment: @Dilaton Any rights are due to Internet Archive, not me. It seems that it is fine (at least I think so; I it for endorsing/linking them, not any other product or so).

Answer (score 13):

[image: Internet Archive WaybackMachine]

Comment: '+1', How I missed this :-p

Comment: It disappeared from imgur.com for some reason. Strange... I did uploaded it once again. In any case [the png and the Gimp source is here](https://gist.github.com/stared/a9538e926e05f0a5b157).

Answer (score 13):

[image: arXiv.org: the biggest open-access e-print repository for maths and physics]

Comment: [Shamelessly stolen form Physics.SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5299/184). I know there is one more arXiv, but it should be not a problem.

Comment: Well, I would just like to have the font of `freely available` not vertically stretched `:-(`

Comment: @tohecz I'll fix it in a few days. Image is a Fireworks vector PNG if you have software to read those layers.

Comment: @yo' So after a few days, [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1504/820) is the non-stretched version.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Chemistry - Stack Exchange]

Comment: It would be nice to promote the domain-specific academic sites out there… especially those in beta, which could benefit from the extra traffic/notoriety. So I'm proposing Chemistry's ad…

Comment: For a moment there, I thought StackExchange was advertising food.  You might play that up with "Jello and marshmallows? No, you're just hungry for... *Chemistry* Stack Exchange".

Answer (score 9):

[image: Open Science Federation]

Comment: Also, I recommend their Twitter channel: https://twitter.com/openscience. When I Tweet with links on Open Science I habitually add `@openscience`.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Expats.SE]

Comment: the "SE" tail should be capitalized, right?

Comment: @Ooker You can IMHO pardon it by saying: design decision ;)

Comment: @yo' sorry, but I don't get your joke. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Ooker It's not exactly a joke, it's just a mere fact: in a banner, designed title or whatever, it is in general not necessary to follow the standard capitalization. So IMHO it is fine as is.

Comment: @yo' first time I know. Why not necessary?

Comment: @Ooker That's more a question for [GraphicDesign.SE], but in general: for short and highly exposed pieces of text, design wins over typography (these include banners, ads, various packaging such as boxes, book covers etc.). For longer text, design and typography need to cooperate. (I hope I'm at least somehow clear.) (Moreover, these comments are getting off-topic.)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Open Knowledge Foundation - see how can change the world]

Comment: I came here to actually _do_ this one! Nice, upvoted

Comment: @dgraziotin Great! So how about making one for http://opensciencefederation.com/? :)

Comment: Done: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/978/7112

Comment: Hi @PiotrMigdal do you have an idea how to get some upvotes [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1064/5904)? I dont see what is so bad about a higher-level physics site. But there are some people giving us trouble [elsewhere](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5780/2751) and I suspect that the downvoters here are a proper subset of the 7 scornful and hostil downvoters there who spoil the 9 upvotes ... :-/

Comment: @Dilaton I suspect people from elsewhere. I saw some negative discussions on Physics.SE (however, some of their critique raise important points; I can expand it on priv); here... well, it this tread not too many people visit it at all.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal thanks, I would be interested in what you have to say, maybe in a mail to my PO adress? Yes there initially were some issues, in particular with certain registering processes. But they are now solved. But some (or even quite a number of) people on P.SE continue their scornfulness, hostility, and attacks towards the site and its members, such that a quiet coexistance (not speaking about any constructive relashionship as the one between MO and Math SE) will probably never be possible :-/. We do our best to ignore these things and keep it professional.

Answer (score 8):

[image: PMC is a free full-text archive of biomedical and life sciences journal literature at the U.S. National Institutes of Health's National Library of Medicine]

Comment: Image is a vector Fireworks png.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Explore the Creative Commons licenses for your Open Access content]

Comment: Image is a vector Fireworks png.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Some sites like the twitter account, others don't. It's mechanically run and so the exposure it provides doesn't necessarily match how the site feels it should be broadcast.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Zotero reference manager: free and open source]

Answer (score 2):

[image: SciRate]

Comment: Source: https://gist.github.com/stared/017c8af055f79aa7480f

Answer (score 1):

[image: Europe PubMed Central: a free information resource for biomedical and health researchers]

Comment: Image is a vector Fireworks png.

Answer (score 1):

[image: StackEdit]

Answer (score 1):

[image: arXiv Analytics: another web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Electronic archive for self-archive papers in any area of Psychology, Neuroscience, Linguistics, and any sciences pertinent to the study of cognition]

Comment: Image is a vector Fireworks png. I couldn't find a better resolution image of the logo - please sub one in if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Qiqqa: Essential software for PDF and research management]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: The picture that I have added is not of proper size. I request to everyone who knows about archive.org to make a good descriptive image to add in this post. archive.org is a very good website for educational purposes.

Comment: Internet Archive is a great project, and it would be great to have it here. But we need a better picture!

Comment: OK, done. :) Please upvote [this one](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/980/49).

Comment: A new image has been added. The downvoters may reconsider their downvotes.